# Digital Tachometer

Tags: optics, instrument

How actually does a Non-Contact Type Digital Tachometer work?

The answer which I could find is -

> The infrared light from them tachometer falls on the surface and gets reflected back to the detector on the tachometer. The detector detects the changes in frequency of the reflected light as reflected alternately by the object surface and the contrast spot.

But how does the change in frequency occur? Also, how is it measured by the detector?

(I think the answer above is trying to say- "time lag between the change in frequency helps us to determine rpm.")

Comment: There's multiple types of such devices and they operate using different principles. What specific device are you asking about?

Comment: The light itself is not changing frequency/wavelength, it is the frequency (how often, time between) of the contrast feature modulating the reflected signal.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer you have found indicates, you need to have a contrast spot on the rotating surface to give you the rotational frequency, this is directly related to the rotational speed.

Every time the contrast spot gets under the IR beam you get a change in the intensity of the reflected light this translate to the a freq of the rotation(rounds/sec) via simple translation this can be converted to RPM (60 rpm = 1 round per sec).

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. If the speed of the wheel increases the frequency of when the contrast-spot passes by will increase and this is what is measured by the IR tachometer by sensing the difference in the reflected lights intensity.